# Needing a snippet for listing category specific tags

Tags: categories, tags

I've been out looking for a snippet that will let me organize tags under a certain category and count how many times that tag has been used. Example:

Category name: **Photography**

- Plants (3)
- Animals (14)
- People (4)
- Vehicles (2)

So far what I have is under a custom query and it's as follows:

```
<h3>Identifying Terms Used</h3>
<ul>
    <?php $photographyTags = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => 'photography')); ?>
    <?php if($photographyTags->have_posts()) : while($photographyTags->have_posts()) : $photographyTags->the_post(); ?>
    <?php
        if(get_the_tag_list()) {
            echo get_the_tag_list('<li>','</li><li>','</li>');
        }
    ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

There's a unique issue with this bit of code where when I have a tag that has been used more than once, the name of the tag repeats itself as many times as it's been used. So when I have a tag name like Mesquite Tree and I've used it 4 times, I'll see the word Mesquite Tree repeated 4 times in my list.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: If anyone is still available who knows the answer to this, I would love to hear from you! I still haven't found what I'm looking for...

Comment: Still trying to find an answer to this question if anyone out there has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer. It didn't work the first few times I used it, but after reworking some HTML and with a better grasp of what I'm doing, I was able to put this together. This was from an answer here on W.SE but I can't locate it anymore:

```
<?php
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => get_query_var('cat') ) );

    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
       while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();
          $posttags = get_the_tags();
          if ( $posttags ) {
             foreach( $posttags as $tag ) {
                $all_tags[] = $tag->term_id;
             }
           }
        endwhile;
    endif;

    $tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags); $tags_str = implode(",", $tags_arr);

    $args = array(
        'smallest'  => 14,      'largest'    => 14,
        'unit'      => 'px',    'number'     => 0,
        'format'    => 'list',  'show_count' => 1,
        'include'   => $tags_str
    );
    wp_tag_cloud($args);
?>
```

What I'm able to gather from this is that we need to use a seperate loop and invoke a new WP_Query.

This query is using an array to extract the category that was clicked. Once that happens, the tags listed under that category are gathered up and laid out in a tag cloud.

Then we're reworking the tag cloud to display in a list instead of the typical cloud format. I added `show_count => 1` to show how many times a particular tag was used.

I will post the page on my website that I used it so you can see it in action. Of course, I won't do that until it's done :)

Comment: NOTICE: if you do not have any tags under the category, it will parse an error until you add a tag. It took me awhile to figure this out. So the error I got was this:

`Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\harshclimate\category-photography.php`

What it's saying here is that NULL (which means nothing basically) was used instead of a value in an array. So if you don't add a tag, it'll return nothing (NULL) and you'll get a warning :)